# Fortrabbit And phpMyAdmin: installation clarification

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, paas, fortrabbit

I've been following the Fortrabbit's [guide](http://fortrabbit.com/docs/cookbook/phpmyadmin) to install phpMyAdmin.

I've managed to put the folder in my htdocs, but from what I read I must actually upload it into the app root below htdocs. Problem is the app root has write protection and I can't seem to change permissions via SFTP.

Any solutions?

**Edit**

Solved. I had my Root Path under settings set to `htdocs/public`, so I couldn't hit the phpMyAdmin folder. Setting the Root Path back to `htdocs/` enabled me to access it like normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you read it must go to the app root? I don't see that in the tutorial, but admit I may have missed it. Also, I'm not clear what you mean by "app root".

Note that in this case, there are three different 'root' folders, be careful not to get confused.

1. The file system root, `/`. All the files on your server live here. Depending how fortrabbit configures their system, you may not even have access to this.
2. The web folder root. Files in this folder and below are available online through your webserver.
3. The SFTP root. This also depends on how fortrabbit configures their server, it could be your web root, the file system root, or your home directory. You may be able to change to other folders, or maybe not.

Normally, htdocs is the root or base folder where your webserver is looking for files to serve. It isn't clear from my browsing the fortrabbit site if they do anything odd with their configuration, so this is a close approximation for what most servers look like. For the sake of illustration, we'll pretend that htdocs is in `/var` but it can be anywhere on disk.

So the file system might look a bit like:

```
/
/bin/
/etc/
/home/MichaelHanslo/
/home/MichaelHanslo/budget_presentation.odf
/var/
/var/htdocs/
/var/htdocs/index.html
/var/htdocs/pma/
/var/htdocs/calendar/
/var/htdocs/calendar/modify.php
/var/logs/
```

So in that scenario, going to `http://example.com/` loads the file `/var/htdocs/index.html`, going to `http://example.com/calendar/modify.php` loads `/var/htdocs/calendar/modify.php`. So in most cases, you want to create a folder under `htdocs` for phpMyAdmin; you can call it anything you want (in my example above, I used 'pma'). Anyway, if you don't have permission to create the folder under your web root, then you should definitely ask your host for help, because something isn't right.

Hope that helps clear it up for you.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the thorough explanation. I managed to get it working by placing it within htdocs and adjusting route settings.

Comment: @MichaelHanslo can you explain what you did with the route to get this working? For the life of me I can't figure it out.

Comment: I believe I had my Root Path (under settings) set to my public folder, so I couldn't access phpMyAdmin (Setting root to htdocs/public is typical for a Laravel app). Setting the Root Path back to blank, I could access phpMyAdmin normally. Problem is, when I needed to get my app running again, I had to set the root path back to htdocs/public. Pain in the ass, but that's how I got it working.